# How to find a dictionary based on a value from a list of dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a json file with multiple dictionaries structure in it as show below.

```
[
    {
        "advisories": [
        ],
        "affected_packages": [
        ],
        "bugzilla": "1944167",
        "bugzilla_description": "CVE-2021-3472 xorg-x11-server: XChangeFeedbackControl integer underflow leads to privilege escalation",
        "CVE": "CVE-2021-3472",
        "cvss_score": null,
        "cvss_scoring_vector": null,
        "cvss3_score": "7.8",
        "cvss3_scoring_vector": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:L/PR:L/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:H/A:H",
        "CWE": "CWE-191",
        "public_date": "2021-04-13T14:00:00Z",
        "resource_url": "https://access.redhat.com/hydra/rest/securitydata/cve/CVE-2021-3472.json",
        "severity": "important"
    },
    {
        "advisories": [
        ],
        "affected_packages": [
        ],
        "bugzilla": "1948726",
        "bugzilla_description": "CVE-2020-7924 mongodb: sslAllowInvalidHostnames bypass ssl/tls server certification validation entirely",
        "CVE": "CVE-2020-7924",
        "cvss_score": null,
        "cvss_scoring_vector": null,
        "cvss3_score": "5.1",
        "cvss3_scoring_vector": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:H/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:H/A:N",
        "CWE": "CWE-295",
        "public_date": "2021-04-12T00:00:00Z",
        "resource_url": "https://access.redhat.com/hydra/rest/securitydata/cve/CVE-2020-7924.json",
        "severity": "moderate"
    }
]
```

Now I want to read the json file and fetch the dictionary contents based on a value. Let say my value is `CVE-2020-7924`, then I need to fetch the complete dictionary to a variable or some file.

For example if I search for `CVE-2020-7924` then result should be as below:

```
    {
        "advisories": [
        ],
        "affected_packages": [
        ],
        "bugzilla": "1948726",
        "bugzilla_description": "CVE-2020-7924 mongodb: sslAllowInvalidHostnames bypass ssl/tls server certification validation entirely",
        "CVE": "CVE-2020-7924",
        "cvss_score": null,
        "cvss_scoring_vector": null,
        "cvss3_score": "5.1",
        "cvss3_scoring_vector": "CVSS:3.1/AV:L/AC:H/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:N/I:H/A:N",
        "CWE": "CWE-295",
        "public_date": "2021-04-12T00:00:00Z",
        "resource_url": "https://access.redhat.com/hydra/rest/securitydata/cve/CVE-2020-7924.json",
        "severity": "moderate"
    }
```

Please let me know how I can code for it. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Learn about "How to iterate on a list", "How to access values of a dict given a key"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a json string into a python dict (or in this case a list of dicts), you can use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads). Then, iterate over the list of dicts, look if `dict["CVE"]` equals your value, and if yes, set it to some variable. If you want to export that variable to a json string which you could write to a file, use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps). Example:

```py
import json

CVE_voi = "CVE-2020-7924" # CVE_value_of_interest

inf = open("/path/to/file/containing/data.json", "r")
instr = inf.read()
print(len(instr)) # prints length of json str
print(instr[:100]) # prints first 99 chars of json str
inf.close()
dictlist = json.loads(instr)

for d in dictlist:
    if d["CVE"] == CVE_voi:
        doi = d # copy dict_of_interest in a variable
        outf = open("/path/to/outputfile.json", "w")
        outstr = json.dumps(doi)
        outf.write(outstr)
        outf.close()
        break
else: # print a message when no dict with the given CVE value was found
    print("no dict containing CVE %s could be found" % CVE_voi)
```

Comment: I have tried it, but getting below error with this approach.
```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: @Rajesh there was a small mistake in my code I fixed just now, but which is unrelated to your error. On my machine using Python 3.6 it works without any error.

Comment: @Rajesh I added some debugging prints to the code, please run it again and add an answer containing the output (not a comment, the newlines are getting absorbed there)

Comment: @Rajesh I suspect your JSON file is either empty or contains a newline at the beginning.

Comment: @Rajesh when i delete the contents of the json input file i get the same error

Comment: @Rajesh what did you do to finally make it work ?

Comment: Issue was with my JSON file due to which it was not working. Due to the fact I was pulling data from paginated API my json file had some format issue. I corrected my script to pull the data to my JSON file which resolved the issue. After that using your logic I was able to make it work. Thanks.